# How can I add multiple graphs, select them via dropdown menu and display them with multiple y axis?

Tags: python, plotly, local

I'm new using Plotly and I'm trying to plot multiple graphs, select each one of them via dropdown menu. The thing here is that there is data in the csv file that have more than one Y axis. I want them to be added as I want them to be shown, the two y-axis in one of the selections in the dropdown menu. There's a problem with my code, I'm able to create the dropdown menu and select all the individuals graph but not the ones with multiple y-axis. In this case I put some functioning code, the main problem is that I want in the option 1 to be the two of them together and not in the first one (Option 0). What can I do?

```py
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from plotly.graph_objects import Figure, Scatter
import plotly

import numpy as np


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        # some example data
        x = np.arange(10)
        y = x**2
        x1 = np.arange(10)
        y1 = x1

        # create the plotly figure
        i=0
        estudiosAux=[]
        dataArr=[]
        fig = Figure()
        dictYaux={0:[],1:[[],[]]}
        flag=True
        
        
        for j in range(2):
            if len(dictYaux.get(j))==0:  
                if j>0:
                    flag=False
                d=Scatter(
                        x = x,
                        y = y,
                        name = j,visible = (flag)
                    )
                print("x")
                dataArr.append(d)
                estudiosAux.append(j)
                flag=True
                
            elif len(dictYaux.get(j))>=2: 
                k=0
                while k<len(dictYaux.get(j)):
                    ystr='y'+str(k+1)
                    if j>0:
                        flag=False
                    if k==0:
                        d=Scatter(
                                x = x,
                                y = y,
                                name = j,visible = (flag)
                            )
                        dataArr.append(d)
                        estudiosAux.append(j)
                        print("x")
                    elif k>0:
                        d=Scatter(
                                x = x1,
                                y = y1,name = j
                            )
                        print("x1")
                        dataArr.append(d)
                    flag=True
                    k+=1
        print(dataArr)
        print(estudiosAux)
        fig=Figure(data=dataArr)
        
        buttons=[]
        for study in estudiosAux:
            args = [False] * len(estudiosAux)
            args[i] = True
    
            #create a button object for the country we are on
            button = dict(label = str(study),
            method = "update",
            args=[{"visible": args}])
    
            #add the button to our list of buttons
            buttons.append(button)
            i+=1
        fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[dict(active=0,
                                    buttons=buttons,
                                    x = 0.13,
                                    y = 1.23,
                                    xanchor = 'left',
                                    yanchor = 'top',
                                )])
        fig.update_layout(
            annotations=[
                dict(text="Estudios:", showarrow=False,
                x=1, y=1.2, yref="paper", align="left")
            ]
        )
        # we create html code of the figure
        html = '<html><body>'
        html += plotly.offline.plot(fig, output_type='div', include_plotlyjs='cdn')
        html += '</body></html>'

        # we create an instance of QWebEngineView and set the html code
        plot_widget = QWebEngineView()
        plot_widget.setHtml(html)

        # set the QWebEngineView instance as main widget
        self.setCentralWidget(plot_widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[I want this to be just X^2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSq7r.png)

[In this one I want them to be both, it's giving the opposite visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgjJr.png)

Comment: Try to provide a simple example and read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Hamzah I added some code of what I'm trying to do. I've been since yesterday trying to solve this, but I can't.

Comment: I will try to help you tomorrow.

Comment: Your explanation is not clear but let me tell you what I understood and correct me. You want to add different plots based on the dropdow menu. One of the plots has two y-axes, right?

Comment: @Hamzah exactly, that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: When the user selects 0 only x^2 should be plotted. When the user selects 1 , both plots should be plotted.

Comment: Based on the plots in your question, both options do not contain any plot with 2 y axes.

Comment: I spent long time to do it but I could not. I recommend you asking the following question in Plotly Community: how to add a plot with 2 y-axes with updatemenu Plotly?

Comment: Hi @Hamzah thank you for trying it. Fortunately, I was able to solve it, it was just making some changes in the button's insertion, in the visible args. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Could you please add the answer for the newcomers to benefit from you?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution was simple at the end.
Previous button code:

```py
        buttons=[]
        for study in estudiosAux:
            args = [False] * len(estudiosAux)
            args[i] = True
    
            #create a button object for the country we are on
            button = dict(label = str(study),
            method = "update",
            args=[{"visible": args}])
    
            #add the button to our list of buttons
            buttons.append(button)
            i+=1
```

New code:

```py
        buttons=[]
        k=0     
        for j in range(len(estudios)):
            args = [False] * len(estudiosAux)
            while k<len(estudiosAux) and estudios[j]==estudiosAux[k]:
                args[k] = True
                k+=1
            
            #create a button object for the country we are on
            button = dict(label = str(self.studyDic.get(j)),
            method = "update",
            args=[{"visible": args}])
    
            #add the button to our list of buttons
            buttons.append(button)
            i+=1
```

Adding the WHILE LOOP helps to see if there is a repeated graph NAME in estudiosAux, in that case, it assigns the visualization as True in all of the repeated values CONNECTED TO ONE BUTTON so, without adding another button to the dropdown menu, it shows it correctly in order.